# Installed with or with

Tags: past-tense

I need to convey that the specific software has been installed on all PCs, so which one is right here ?

1. All PCs are installed with adobe now
2. All PCs are with adobe now

Here, Adobe is software name.

Comment: Consider adapting your original wording: *Adobe has been installed on all PCs*.

Comment: Thanks, but i have to respond for this question "Is this complete now?" so i thought of reply like "Yes, all PCs are installed with adobe now"

Comment: If it pertains to how the question is answered, that information should be included in your question text. In any case, you can answer that specific query more simply: *Yes, it is.*

Comment: @Lawrence Passive voice is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Kris, I'm sure you mean "All PCs have Adobe installed now."

Comment: @Kris Interesting recursive comment :) . Yes, modern writing tends to promote the active voice, but that doesn’t preclude a well-placed passive.

Comment: @bookmanu Yes, oversight. Tx.

Comment: "Are" doesn't sound right, use have. "All PCs have Adobe installed now." Do not drop "installed", that word is important here.

Comment: @sasikals26 See also: [ell.se] Good Luck.

Comment: "All PCs come with Adobe now" is an alternate way of saying that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question gives the best wording:

"All PCs have Adobe software installed" or "Adobe software has been installed on all PCs."

"Installed with" followed by a noun is non-standard; it's more likely to be used with an action -- "...installed with care" or "...tweezers"

Your #2 example is incorrect because "are with" is used to mean as actual physical proximity if no auxiliary verb is included. "John is with his mom." "Mary is going with her brother."